# Hibernate issue : must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, postgresql

Query I want to run:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month',UA.activity_date),SUM(UA.points) FROM user_activity UA
WHERE UA.activity_date > '01/01/2014' AND UA.activity_date < '12/31/2014' 
GROUP BY date_trunc('month',UA.activity_date)
ORDER BY date_trunc('month',UA.activity_date)
```

Expected Results:

```
03/01/2014 00:00:00 66.04000000000000000
05/01/2014 00:00:00 13.50000000000000000
07/01/2014 00:00:00 27.00000000000000000
08/01/2014 00:00:00 26.00000000000000000
09/01/2014 00:00:00 13.50000000000000000
```

When I use Hibernate to run that query, I get this error thrown:

```
ERROR: column "useractivi0_.activity_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

To fix that, I have modified the above query as :

```
SELECT date_trunc('month',UA.activity_date),SUM(UA.points) FROM user_activity UA
WHERE UA.activity_date > '01/01/2014' AND UA.activity_date < '12/31/2014' 
GROUP BY date_trunc('month',UA.activity_date),***UA.activity_date***
ORDER BY date_trunc('month',UA.activity_date)
```

But, the results are wrong:

```
03/01/2014 00:00:00 25.40000000000000200
03/01/2014 00:00:00 25.40000000000000200
03/01/2014 00:00:00 15.24000000000000000
05/01/2014 00:00:00 13.50000000000000000
07/01/2014 00:00:00 9.00000000000000000
07/01/2014 00:00:00 18.00000000000000000
08/01/2014 00:00:00 4.50000000000000000
```

How can I fix this?

When I run the first query from my toad shell directly on the db, it seems to work just fine. However, when I run the same query from code using Hibernate I get that error.

Comment: Could you display the query generated by Hibernate ?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I use Hibernate to run the query"? Do you use native SQL or are you using HQL? All I can see in the question is bunch of SQL and no HQL.

Comment: I am using HQL , this is the query generated by hibernate
Query : [SELECT date_trunc(:aggregateBy,UA.date),SUM(UA.points) FROM UserActivity UA WHERE UA.date > :fromDate AND UA.date < :toDate GROUP BY date_trunc(:aggregateBy,UA.date),UA.date ORDER BY date_trunc(:aggregateBy,UA.date)]

Comment: I had to put in the "UA.date" in the GROUP BY clause to get the query to work, but really dont want to do that (results not what I expect)

Answer (score 0):

You can try having your sum and date_trunc in subquery , something like below:

```
SELECT colA, SUM(colB) FROM (SELECT date_trunc('month',UA.activity_date) colA,SUM(UA.points) colB FROM user_activity UA
WHERE UA.activity_date > '01/01/2014' AND UA.activity_date < '12/31/2014' 
GROUP BY UA.activity_date
ORDER BY date_trunc('month',UA.activity_date))sub GROUP BY colA
```

Just do group by in outerquery again. See if it helps.

Comment: Doesnt look like hibernate likes that : org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 29 [SELECT colA, SUM(colB) FROM (SELECT date_trunc(:aggregateBy,UA.date) colA,SUM(UA.points) colB FROM com.MWBFServer.Activity.UserActivity UA WHERE UA.date > :fromDate AND UA.date < :toDate GROUP BY UA.date ORDER BY date_trunc(:aggregateBy,UA.date))sub GROUP BY colA]

Comment: String hql = "SELECT colA, SUM(colB) FROM (SELECT date_trunc(:aggregateBy,UA.date) colA,SUM(UA.points) colB FROM UserActivity UA";
  hql += " WHERE UA.date > :fromDate AND UA.date < :toDate";
  hql += " GROUP BY UA.date";
  hql += " ORDER BY date_trunc(:aggregateBy,UA.date))sub GROUP BY colA"; 
  Query query = session.createQuery(hql);

Comment: you cannot pass sql query to createQuery, instead you need to use createSQLQuery. createQuery is for HQL. In your case change it to session.createSQLQurey(hql);

Comment: I did want to use the hibernate query language to make my code more portable across dbs. So, was using the regular createQuery (instead of createSQLQuery (with Class names and property names instead of table names and column names). But Hibernate complains (error above). Is there any way to do this without using createSQLQuery ?

Comment: you need to convert your sql query to a HQL query then. Have a look at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries to know how to build subqueries in HQL

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date_trunc('month',UA.activity_date) act_date,
       SUM(UA.points) point_sum 
FROM user_activity UA
WHERE UA.activity_date > '01/01/2014' AND UA.activity_date < '12/31/2014' 
GROUP BY act_date
ORDER BY act_date
```